# What does this block of Python code do?

Tags: python, file, file-io, random

I am writing a python hangman program, and I wanted to be able to randomly generate a word from a file, and it works. But I got one line of this code off a website, and it helps me to do what I need to do, but I dont know **how**.

Thanks

```
   offset = random.randint(0, os.stat(filename)[6]) # ?????
   fd = file(filename, 'rb')
   fd.seek(offset)
   fd.readline()
   return fd.readline()
```

Comment: In the Future, it would be helpful if you stated which line you got off the website, so that we know which line to help you with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`os.stat(filename)[6]` simply returns the size, in bytes, of the file named by `filename`. You can read more about `os.stat()` [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat).

`random.randint(...)` generates a random integer between zero and `n`, where `n` is the size of the file obtained via `os.stat()`.

The code then seeks to that (random) position in the file. The chances are that this position is in the middle of a line. Therefore, the code reads the partial line and discards it. It then reads the next line and returns it.

Finally, the code has a bug: if the random position lands on the last line of the file, the second `readline()` will have nothing to read.

**edit:** Also, as noted by @Russell Borogove in the comments, this method doesn't ensure that lines are chosen with equal probability.

Comment: Actually, I was just wondering about the first line, but thanks anyway. U were alot of help.

Comment: @AhmadGaffoor: I've explained the rest in order to expose the bug I mention in the last paragraph.

Comment: Note also that this is a fast, but non-uniform, way of getting a random line from a file. Lines immediately following long lines in the file will have a higher chance of being selected than lines following short lines.

Comment: Also of note is that this code will *never* return the first line.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon aix's answer, after we have a random integer within the "range" of the file, we go to that location with `fd.seek(offset)`. We use `fd.readline()` to drop the line we are on, and move to the next one. Then we use `fd.readline()` to return the entire current line we are on.

Note that if you end up on the last line of the file, you will return an empty string. To demonstrate set your offset to `os.stat(filename)[6] - 1` and use readline twice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add this as a comment, but couldn't include a code example.

Here's the code you included with the last line/first line bug fixed:

```
size = os.stat(filename)[6]
offset = random.randint(0, size) # ?????
fd = file(filename, 'rb')
fd.seek(offset)
fd.readline()
if fd.tell() == size:
    fd.seek(0)
return fd.readline()
```

It doesn't fix the uniformity problem as described by @russell-borogove.